# C# Winforms. Textchanged event will stop working when clear button is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

Hello i have a POS system which has two datagridview, When i scan a barcode, The product is automatically added to the cart datagridview via textchanged event.

It is working fine but when i click the "clear button", The textchanged event will stop working. Any idea is appreciated thank you.

clear button code:

```
  private void btnClearcart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvPOScart.Rows.Clear();
        dgvPOScart.Refresh();

        if (dgvPOSproduct.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dgvPOSproduct.DataSource = null;
        }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Products");

            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    cnn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ProductID, BrandName, GenericName, Quantity, SellingPrice, Dosage, Form, S,P, VE ,  Barcode , Category , Description from Products where Status = 'Active' and Quantity > 0", cnn))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dgvPOSproduct.DataSource = dt;
                    productwidth();

                }
            }

    }
```

Code to populate product datagridview in form load:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable("Products");

    private void dgvProductNew()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    cnn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ProductID, BrandName, GenericName, Quantity, SellingPrice, Dosage, Form, S,P, VE ,  Barcode , Category , Description from Products where Status = 'Active' and Quantity > 0", cnn))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dgvPOSproduct.DataSource = dt;

                    productwidth();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

textchanged event code :

```
    private void txtBarcodeSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        selectedRow = null;

        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Barcode like '{0}%' ", txtBarcodeSearch.Text);
        productwidth();

        if (txtBarcodeSearch.Text.Length == 13)
        {

            if (dgvPOSproduct.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                selectedRow = 0;
            }

            if (selectedRow.HasValue)
            {
                addcartbarcode();
                txtBarcodeSearch.Clear();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You misunderstand how the barcode scanner puts the text into the TextBox.  The scanner itself knows absolutely nothing about Winforms and TextBox controls.  All it does is put text into the focused window.  So you have a focus problem, clicking the button changes the focus from the TextBox to the Button.  That kills the barcode scanner, it can't put text into the button.  And the TextChanged event is no longer raised.  You'll have to explicitly set the focus back, add txtBarcodeSearch.Focus() to the Click event handler.

Comment: But sir my problem is not on the focused. even when i give the focus back to the textbox its not triggering anymore after pressing clear button. i think the problem is in data table but im not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked putting a debugger on TextChanged Event? because it must fire on changing the text of the textbox.

So, i think this is not your problem.

but the following may be your problem if i am not wrong.

your `txtBarcodeSearch_TextChanged` event always fires and the row filter also filters the rows as needed, but not of the same `DataTable` object i.e dt.
that means you are not filtering the same datatable object. because of you have declared the dt object twice, one public and other privately in `btnClearcart_Click` event when you click on clear button as

```
private void btnClearcart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvPOScart.Rows.Clear();
    dgvPOScart.Refresh();

    if (dgvPOSproduct.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dgvPOSproduct.DataSource = null;
    }

        //DataTable dt = new DataTable("Products");  //this was your issue
        dt = new DataTable("Products");            //this will work

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                cnn.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ProductID, BrandName, GenericName, Quantity, SellingPrice, Dosage, Form, S,P, VE ,  Barcode , Category , Description from Products where Status = 'Active' and Quantity > 0", cnn))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                dgvPOSproduct.DataSource = dt;
                productwidth();

            }
        }

}
```

So, after clear button click your datagridview binds to a new datatable instance each time you click on clear button. but your textchage event was filtering the first dt object (datatable) only which is no more bound to the datagridview.